# hideColumns() number of columns parameter based on referenced column index Google Apps Script Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to do `hideColumns()` in google sheets. The starting column is always fixed (column B) but the number of columns to hide is variable depending on a date function. Each cell in the header row has a date, and I want to hide all columns with a date before today's date. So I did a lookup and found the index number of the column with today's date and I want to simply reference that index minus 1 to come up with the number of columns to hide.

The below will work if I hard code a value for number of columns (e.g. 3) but it won't work if I reference `i` or even try to redefine `i` as a variable

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Get column index of yesterday's date
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daily Tracker');
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lastColumn).getDisplayValues().flat(); //create an array of data from row 1
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy")
    if (data[i] == dateToday)
    {  
      return i;
      break;
    }
    var hiddenColumnCount = i - 1;
    // Number of columns to hide = index - 1 (e.g. 10/14/2020 = index of 8. I need to hide columns 10/6/2020 through 10/13/2020, which = 7 columns so i - 1)
    // Hide all columns from column B through column with yesterday's date
    sheet.hideColumns(2,hiddenColumnCount);
  }
}
```

I don't know if `i` is unable to be referenced because maybe it's a string and not a number since I flattened the array from above. But I tried converting to a number using `parseInt()` but not sure if it worked or if it's the right thing. I've also tried defining `var hiddenColumnCount = 0` above the for statement and then instead of `return i` I tried typing `hiddenColumnCount = i - 1` but this didn't work either
I'm new to programming and try to look everything up on my own but I've hit a road block

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to return anything in an onOpen() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `Each cell in the header row has a date, and I want to hide all columns with a date before today's date.` and `I want to simply reference that index minus 1 to come up with the number of columns to hide.`, in your situation, when the date of today can be found, you want to hide the columns "B" to the left side of the column with the date.

#### Modifcation points:

- In your case, it seems that the column number of the date of today can be retrieved. I think that this can be used for achieving your goal.
- When the array of `data` is looped, please modify the condition of for loop from `for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {` to `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`. When `i <= data.length` is used, the last loop is the index of out of array.
- In your script, when the date of today is found, the script is finished.
- When `hideColumns` is used, I think that in your case, this can be put to the out of for loop.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  // Get column index of yesterday's date
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daily Tracker');
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,lastColumn).getDisplayValues().flat(); //create an array of data from row 1
  
  // I modified below script.
  var columnNumber = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var dateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    if (data[i] == dateToday) {
      columnNumber = i + 2;
    }
  }
  sheet.hideColumns(2, columnNumber - 2);
  
  // Here, columnNumber is the column number of the found date.
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the date is the ascending order from the column "B". Please be careful this. When above modified script is not the result you expect, I think that it might be required to confirm the situation of Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)

Comment: @823g4n8901 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Daily Tracker');    
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat(); 
  for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]==Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/yyyy")){break;}else{sh.hideColumn(i+2);}
  }
}
```